# How to change options in select tag in javascript using console?

Tags: javascript

```
<select name="ethinicity" >
            <option value="type1">Asian</option>
            <option value="type2">African</option>
            <option value="type3">Caucasion</option>
            <option value="type4">Hispanics</option>
            <option value="type5">Other Populated Groups</option>
</select>
```

I am using

```
document.getELementsByname("ethinicity").value="type2"
```

to change its value,but it donot work in that way,why i can't do like this? and give me other way to do this but i donot want to put this in `form` and then changing it like

```
document.formName.ethinicity.value="type2"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not duplicate i already checked all of them, but cant find any single answer which is specific to my question.

Comment: you need to change the `selectedIndex` of your `select`...This is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
document.getElementsByName("ethinicity")[0].selectedIndex = 1;
```

You should give your select an id like this:

```
<select id="ethinicity" name="ethinicity" >

document.getElementById("ethinicity").selectedIndex = 1;
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("ethinicity")[0].value ="type2";`why i cannot do like this

Comment: @sony never said you couldn't but I would recommend using an `id` instead of `name` to retrieve elements...

Comment: thnks, i will use this.

Comment: @sony no problem glad I could help!

Comment: If i use index `1` instead of `0` like this `document.getElementsByName("ethinicity")[1].value ="type2" ` what would happen actually, as in console nothing is changing.why so?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the name of the elements as a parameter to the function you are using to select them alongwith first array index:

```
document.getELementsByName("ethinicity")[0].value="type2"
```

Comment: I am already doing this, i mentioned it

Comment: you are not doing this. please check your question you have missing parenthesis.

Comment: yeah u r right but still it was wrong u forgot to add array index i think.